# Tensorflow - Same Padding Calculation

Tags: tensorflow, padding

I have the following parameters:

```
in_height = 28
in_width = 28
stride (s) = 2
padding (p) = 'SAME'
```

The idea of 'SAME' padding is when s = 1 then input map and output map dimensions (height, width) should remain same

So if I should be able to get the padding size using the following:

```
(28 + 2*p - 5) + 1 = 28
Solving gives p = 2
```

which means there should be a padding on each side of 2

Using `p=2` the output map size would be:

```
(28 + 4 -5)/2 + 1 = 14
```

From Tensorflow documentation, `Same Padding`:

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))

pad_along_height = max((out_height - 1) * strides[1] +
                    filter_height - in_height, 0)
pad_along_width = max((out_width - 1) * strides[2] +
                   filter_width - in_width, 0)
pad_top = pad_along_height // 2
pad_bottom = pad_along_height - pad_top
pad_left = pad_along_width // 2
pad_right = pad_along_width - pad_left
```

To follow the above:

```
out_height = ceil(28.0/2.0) = 14.0
out_width = ceil(28.0/2.0) = 14.0
```

Hence

```
pad_along_height = max((14.0 -1)*2 + 5 - 28,0) = 3
pad_along_width = max((14.0 -1)*2 + 5 - 28,0) = 3

pad_top = 3 // 2 = 1
pad_bottom = 3//2 - pad_top = 2
pad_left = pad_along_width // 2 = 1
pad_right = pad_along_width - pad_left = 2
```

So does it mean that the image should be padded 1 on top and 2 on bottom similarly on the left and right?

Comment: `pad_top = 3 // 2 = 1` --> `pad_bottom = 3//2 - pad_top = 2`. should'nt pad_bottom = 0`{1 - 1}`

Comment: There is a mistake in write-up. It should be `pad_bottom = pad_along_height - pad_top`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at the Tensorflow documentation they actually validate the thought:

> Note that the division by 2 means that there might be cases when the
>   padding on both sides (top vs bottom, right vs left) are off by one.
>   In this case, the bottom and right sides always get the one additional
>   padded pixel. For example, when pad_along_height is 5, we pad 2 pixels
>   at the top and 3 pixels at the bottom. Note that this is different
>   from existing libraries such as cuDNN and Caffe, which explicitly
>   specify the number of padded pixels and always pad the same number of
>   pixels on both sides.